# Is there a TeamViewer like service for command-line access to a Window desktop?

Tags: command-line-interface, remote-access

I want to connect to a remote Windows 10 Desktop computer via the command line. I know I could install an SSH server, but then I need to configure the router, or a VPN. Is there a service (preferably free) similar to TeamViewer that allows command line access to a Windows computer? It would seem that would be easier and less demanding since it doesn't require sending the graphical interface.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding - would Powershell Remoting do the job for you?  If it won't, please describe why and that will let me home in on the right thing for you. https://www.faqforge.com/windows/create-powershell-session-remote-computer/

Comment: Logmein Pro has a "command line only" option for remote connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PS remoting should help depending where you are coming from. Inside your network run this - `Enter-PSSession [-ComputerName]`